# Sort trash by date post was trashed

Tags: trash

Is it possible to sort the trash for post by the last post added to trash.

EG: I trash post 4,2,1,3,5

I would like these post to be sorted in trash by the last post trashed, so they would appear in this order:
4
2
1
3
5

Currently the date filter sorts the trash by the date the post was created not the date sent to trash, i need to sort by the date sent to trash

Comment: Just for interest sake, why do you need to do this?

Comment: The client wants to know when he has trashed or removed certain items from the website. Do you know if this is doable?